# Check if possible sum exists

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, algorithms

Suppose I am given a set of $N$ Natural Numbers, I have to find if it is possible to pick any $K$ numbers from the set such that the sum of the $K$ numbers equals to $S$. All $K$ numbers should be distinct.

For example,

```
N=5 , K=3 , S=10
One of the  ways = 5+3+2
N=5 , K=3 , S=18
No Ways
```

Comment: You haven't shown the sets of $N$ numbers.  It appears that the $N$ numbers are the set $\{1,2,3\ldots N\}$.  Is that correct?  If so, what is the minimum sum of $K$ numbers?  What is the maximum sum of $K$ numbers?  All totals in that range are achievable, and no others.

Comment: Is this some active homework/competition question? Someone else [posted](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906163/choose-n-elements-from-a-set-where-their-summand-equals-s) this exact question today.