# Choose $n$ elements from a set where their summand equals $S$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Given a set size $n$ consisting of elements from $1 \rightarrow n$, choose $k$ elements from the set such that their summand equals $S$, if possible

For ex: $n = 5$ (i.e the choices $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$), $k = 3$ and $S=9$ then 
elements chosen are $1,3$ and $5$

So is there a general formula or a general approach on how to choose such elements? because n and k can be really large.

You can give me the gist or go ahead.

Comment: This is the typical problem which can be solved with a greedy algorithm.

Comment: why a negative vote? What have I done wrong?

Comment: @Crostul can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, you start with an empty list $L$, and the list $N= \{ 1, \dots , n \}$. Pick the largest number from $N$ and put it inside $L$, and repeat this process until the sum of the elements inside $L$ is too big (larger than $S$). When you are at this point, simply remove from $L$ the last element, and put inside $L$ the correct element in such a way that the sum is exactly $S$.

Comment: OK, actually this process does not work, since it does not ensure that the final result has exactly $k$ elements.

Comment: @user42638 Do the $k$ elements have to be unique?

Comment: @Crostul Also you can just choose to continue the algorithm's search if $\vert{L}\vert \neq k$. If you ensure your search is in order, then this will eventually find the desired $L$.

Comment: @gowrath yes, they have to be unique. I've got the idea now...I'll post the detailed answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can first deduce that $S \in \left[1, \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right] \subset \mathbb{N}.$ Then for an $S$ in this discrete interval the formula you seek would be the partitions of $S$ into $k$ distinct parts less than or equal to $n$, for which I believe there is no closed form formula, but looking into partitions may get you more information. There may be a generating function for this but I am not positive.

There is discussion of the generation function for partitions of $S$ into just distinct parts here [The number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts equals the number of partitions of $n$ into odd parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54961/the-number-of-partitions-of-n-into-distinct-parts-equals-the-number-of-partiti) but partitions of $S$ into $k$ distinct parts all less than or equal to $n$ would certainly require more work.